# Oracle: using WHERE ROWNUM = 1

Tags: oracle

chaps and chapettes

Just a quick question. I need to return only one row from a stored proc., but no matter where I place the WHERE clause, I get errors. Can somebody take a look at the (cut-down due to sheer length) code and let me know where it should go, please?

```
SELECT        **values** 

INTO          **variables**                  

FROM          **table**

_WHERE        ROWNUM = 1_

INNER JOIN    **other table**
ON            **join target**
ORDER BY      **sort criteria**;

_WHERE        ROWNUM = 1_
```

Thanks

Comment: include where you put the `rownum`

Comment: The WHERE attempts are now included in the question, at the lines designated by _

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were almost correct. You put the WHERE clause after the JOINs, but before the ORDER BY.

```
SELECT        **values** 

INTO          **variables**                  

FROM          **table**

INNER JOIN    **other table**
ON            **join target**

_WHERE        ROWNUM = 1_

ORDER BY      **sort criteria**;
```

However, this won't do what you might think - the ORDER BY is evaluated AFTER the where clause; which means this will just pick the first record it finds (that satisfies the join criteria), and will then sort that row (which obviously is a no-op).

The other answers (e.g. IvoTops') give ideas of how to get the first record according to the sort criteria.

Answer (score 9):

I believe this is the way to structure rownum queries

```
SELECT * FROM 
INTO **Variables * *
( SELECT * FROM X 
  WHERE Y 
  ORDER BY Z
) 
WHERE ROWNUM = 1;
```

Comment: If I try this, it complains that I'm missing a right parenthesis.

Comment: Does it work without errors on your database in a very simple form on a simple table?

Comment: This is the right way, you must have missed something to be getting that error.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT        **values** 
INTO          **variables**                  
FROM 
    ( SELECT        **values** 
                  , ROW_MUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY  **sort criteria**) AS rn
      FROM          **table**
      INNER JOIN    **other table**
      ON            **join target**  
    ) tmp 
WHERE        rn = 1 ;
```

Check also this blog post: [Oracle: ROW_NUMBER() vs ROWNUM](http://explainextended.com/2009/05/06/oracle-row_number-vs-rownum/)

Answer (score 1):

little bit late, but I got a similar problem and I solved it like this:

```sql
SELECT **values** 
INTO **variables** 
FROM **table**
WHERE **condition**
ORDER BY **sort criteria**
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY;
```

Regards